# VsHub.exe showing up in task manager after exiting Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

So after I have closed down Visual Studio 2015 (Community) `VsHub.exe` and `Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe` they continue to show up in the task manager.

Is there a way for me to have them close at the same time I close Visual Studio?

Comment: No.  They'll quit but they will always outlast your patience staring at Task Manager.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, yeah I stopped looking at it and checked again a few moments ago and it is gone.  Thanks for the help.